# Prohibit injection via access modifier

Tags: java, cdi, visibility, code-injection

Consider a facade

```
public interface LoggingFacade {
    void log(String logMessage);
}
```

with corresponding bean

```
public class LoggingBean implements LoggingFacade {
    @Inject
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @Override
    public void log(String logMessage) {
        loggingService.log(logMessage);
    }
}
```

with

```
public class LoggingService {
    public void log(String logMessage) {
        // some logic and logging
    }
}
```

They all lie in the same package. I want every programmer to call the facade and not to call the service directly (in other packages). So I tried to add a protected constructor to `LoggingService`.

```
public class LoggingService {
    protected LoggingService() {
    }

    public void log(String logMessage) {
        // some logic and logging
    }
}
```

Sadly, this does not prohibit the usage (injection) of `LoggingService` in other classes. Or in other words

```
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    public void foo() {
        loggingService.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

works. Do you have any idea how to prohibit the usage of `LoggingService` so every user has to call the `LoggingFacade`?

Comment: Can you not just make the logging service not public?

Comment: Which modifier do you suggest?

Comment: Do you want the `LoggingService` to be a CDI bean? (If yes why?) If no, you can make the class package-private (and probably `@Vetoed` too). Rationale: you want to prohibit everyone else from using it, so why expose it in the first place? The fact that it is even in the same package as the facade makes me think it is an implementation detail of the facade.

Comment: Just remove the public modifier from the classes that you don't want to be visible from outside the package.

Comment: If I make `LoggingService` package protected it can still be injected in any other class. I want the Logging Service to be a CDI bean, because I want to inject it in my `LoggingService`. I don't want to put the logic in the facadeBean, because facades should be free from logic and just delegate. The solution we went for at the moment is to add a package protected constructor with an argument. This way you can't inject it anywhere else. In the bean we created the object via `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this as long as you don't have Java 9 module system.

With Java 9 you could define a separate module that does not export the LoggingService.

Comment: With Jigsaw...I guess you would not be warned by the IDE you are using. I guess you will get the error at compile time!? I am not sure how usable this is. It shadows a lot.

Comment: With an IDE that supports Java 9 like most of doing now you can't use a class that is not exported. Like in IntelliJ https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/java-9-and-intellij-idea/